# Graphics card problem

Tags: drivers, graphics, ati

I'm having a ATI Radeon HD 4550 graphics card.
The performance of my desktop is faster and smoother without install the driver for it.
After installing the driver, the performance of my desktop is slower and less smooth.
What should I do? Install the driver or not?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation with some AMD/ATI radeon graphic cards on Ubuntu 11.04 and above is that you NOT install the proprietary drivers from AMD. I've made the experience that flash games and movies are slower with the proprietary driver and that you can have problems with supend/hypernation.
With Ubuntu 10.10 and lower, it's better to install the proprietary driver, there are no performance issues and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

1. Install package `compizconfig-settings-manager`.
2. Run it.
3. Click the General - OpenGL icon.
4. Uncheck the "Sync to VBlank" option.

If this does not help, you can just set it back the way it was, but it helped my system a lot.